# Inconsistency when parsing text with geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following piece of code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(x=1:4,y=c(1,2,1,2),z=c('.00019','.00020','.00021','2.2 %*% 10^-5'))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,label=z))+geom_text(parse=TRUE)
```

Will generate the following figure:
[image]

How do I avoid converting the string '.00020' to '2e-04'?

Answer (score 3):

```
try this :

options(scipen=10)
```

Comment: this works great! I still get that .00020 is converted to 0.0002 though, while I would rather keep the trailing 0 there. Is there any additional magic that can be done?